# Modules homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was trying to make this exercise. If $M_1$, $M_2$ are submodules of $M$ and $M_1\leq M_2$ then the function $\varphi : M/M_1 \to M/M_2$ such that $\varphi (\bar{m})=\bar{m}$ is a surjective homomorphism. It is not difficult to show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, but setting a $\bar{n}\in M/M_2$ I couldn't prove that $\bar{n}\in M/M_1$ which shows the surjection. This suggest me this is not the way to prove this fact.

Comment: Isn't that trivial though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notation you chose is confusing for this purpose. Instead of writing $x \mapsto \overline x$ for the quotient map $M \longrightarrow M/M_i$, I'll write it as $x \mapsto x + M_i$. Now, the map $M/M_1 \longrightarrow M/M_2$ can be written as $x + M_1 \mapsto x + M_2$. The condition that $M_1 \subseteq M_2$ ensures that this is well defined.

With this notation the path is more clear. Take some element $\alpha \in M/M_2$. Then we can pick a representive $x$ of the equivalence class $\alpha$ by writing $\alpha = x + M_2$ for some $x \in M$. Then $x + M_1 \in M/M_1$ and we have $x + M_1 \mapsto x + M_2 = \alpha$. Hence, $\alpha$ is in the image of the map $M/M_1 \longrightarrow M/M_2$, so this map is onto.

Answer (score 1):

The projection $\pi_2 : M \to M/M_2$ is surjective, and its kernel $M_2$ contains $M_1$. By the [fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) it therefore induces a surjective homomorphism $f : M/M_1 \to M/M_2$ characterized by $f \circ \pi_1 = \pi_2$. (Direct argument for surjectivity: Since $f \circ \pi_1$ is surjective, $f$ is surjective.) This, by the way, also shows that you don't need to (re)prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, it just follows from the general theorem.